# How to override * in Oracle SQL using roles?

Tags: sql, oracle, roles

`Table Emp` consists of 10 columns.How to override * to get not all columns, `just 3`, using roles? For example query

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
```

returns only 3 columns for user.

Comment: There's no way to restrict the number of columns returned based on roles. You might use views instead.

Comment: You could maybe [mask the column values with VPD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm#i1014682), but that isn't quite what you want. Using `*` isn't good practice anyway, but if you want users to not be able to see some data if they do use it, for privacy reasons, then VPD might be part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only INSERT, UPDATE, and REFERENCES privileges can be granted at the column level. Instead you can create View as shown below.

```
SQL> create view temp as select col1,col2,col3 from emp;
SQL> grant select on temp to someone;
```

And the user `someone` can access the view as:

```
SQL> conn someone/*****
SQL> select * from hr.temp;
```

Comment: What is  hr means?

Comment: `hr` is a user who owns the `emp` table. :)

Comment: @I.James - hr is a "user" created by default in every installation of Oracle. It is there for learning purposes, and people can use it and refer to it for examples in discussions like this one.